# Echo randomly selected DIV

Tags: php

I have no idea how to approach this and cannot find any resources for the same sort of thing so anyone to point in the correct direction would be appreciated.

I was trying to generate a random number in PHP and then write this to a file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129984/writing-the-same-random-number-to-a-file-and-displaying-a-div-based-on-random-se?noredirect=1#comment120420237_68129984). I'm not sure now if this is the best approach. New question created now that I've done furthee research and changed the scope.

I'm looking to show a random DIV that I need to be able to add a maximum number to. I don't know if to cycle between numbers or ID's but the general feel would be like this.

```html
<div id="day-1">
<p>Show if Day 1 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-2">
<p>Show if Day 2 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-3">
<p>Show if Day 3 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-4">
<p>Show if Day 4 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-5">
<p>Show if Day 5 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-6">
<p>Show if Day 6 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-7">
<p>Show if Day 7 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-8">
<p>Show if Day 8 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-9">
<p>Show if Day 9 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>

<div id="day-10">
<p>Show if Day 10 is randomly chosen</p>
</div>
```

I don't want every DIV loaded so I only want to echo the randomly chosen DIV and nothing else.

I was using this to choose a random number and then write it

```
<?php
  $min=1;
  $max=100;
  echo rand($min,$max);
  $file = fopen("./randomnumber.txt","a+ \n");
   fwrite($file,$min,$max);
   fclose($file);
?>
```

But it writes a different number to the one output. I need to store to a file each random number that was put out. I know this doesn't work but my current idea is to show each corresponding DIV based on the random number. I'm not sure how else to echo just one random DIV so not everything has to load.

```
<?php
    $min=1;
    $max=10; // I'd update this to 11 and then add an 11th DIV when another day is added.
    echo rand($min,$max);
    $file = fopen("./randomnumber.txt","a+ \n");
    fwrite($file,$min,$max);
    fclose($file);


 if (rand === '1') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-1">
        <p>Show if Day 1 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
      ";
  }
  
else if (rand === '2') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-2">
        <p>Show if Day 2 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }

else if (rand === '3') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-3">
        <p>Show if Day 3 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }

else if (rand === '4') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-4">
        <p>Show if Day 4 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }
  
  else if (rand === '5') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-5">
        <p>Show if Day 5 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }
  
  else if (rand === '6') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-6">
        <p>Show if Day 6 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }
  
  else if (rand === '7') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-7">
        <p>Show if Day 7 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }
  
  else if (rand === '8') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-8">
        <p>Show if Day 8 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }
  
  else if (rand === '9') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-9">
        <p>Show if Day 9 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }
  
  else if (rand === '10') {
      echo "
      
        <div id="day-10">
        <p>Show if Day 10 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>
      
            ";
  }


?>
```

Pointers to resources in comments or an answer that would echo just one random DIV would be incredibly appreciated because I don't want to push all of the code to the page and have to use extra JS and CSS because it would too massively impact load times.

There's then this approach using shuffle but I'd then still need to write the selected random DIV to a file too so I know what's been output so do I ID them all with numbers or `day-1`, how would I then know the choice made to save this to a text file and is shuffle random enough and an array okay rather than echo and else statements.

```
<?php
$day_array = array(

    '<div id="day-1">
        <p>Show if Day 1 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-2">
        <p>Show if Day 2 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-3">
        <p>Show if Day 3 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-4">
        <p>Show if Day 4 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-5">
        <p>Show if Day 5 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-6">
        <p>Show if Day 6 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-7">
        <p>Show if Day 7 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-8">
        <p>Show if Day 8 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-9">
        <p>Show if Day 9 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-10">
        <p>Show if Day 10 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

);

shuffle($day_array);
for ($i = 1;$i < 2;$i++)
{
    echo array_shift($day_array);
}

?>
```

Thank you in advance, I have an idea but don't know how to execute randomly or if shuffle would be acceptable.

Comment: The last part of my question uses an array, my issue then comes with saving what was shown to a text file. My initial approach was to save the random number and then echo the DIV based on that but the random number that saved wasn't the same that was output @Remy

Comment: How does the content get generated in each of these DIVs?

Comment: What's your question @Samir? Another DIV would be manually added each time new content became available if that's what you're asking. I don't know if to pick a random mumber, save the number then output based on that or if to use an array but then I don't know how I'd save which DIV ID was shown if not using echo and basing off a random selection.

Comment: You need to select one random number and use it throughout the day i.e. one randomly chosen content will be visible to users for an entire day. On the next day, you need to again choose a new random content and show it. Is this what you intend to do?

Comment: On every page load a new day would be shown. So if you took an image every day for 365 days there would be 365 DIVs and whenever the page was reloaded a different one would be shown. That's why I tried to echo based on a random number. The array at the end of my question works fine but I don't then know how to save the DIV ID to a text file too just so I have a reference of how many times each DIV has been selected. The array works w/o the random but echo seemed easier to echo based on a random number once already saved @Samir

Comment: So, say if `day-7` is selected and then `day-4` I'd want to write both of those values to a line in a text file. The number chosen in the echo example reflects the div that would be shown so I decided to do it that way because then I'd know based on the number written. If I'm using an array I need a way of writing the selected DIV ID in `day_array` but `fwrite($file,$day_array);` doesn't work so I think my first approach might be better than an array even though the array works fine unless it's possible to write the same selection to a file because with the number it wrote different @Samir

Comment: Sorry for too many questions, but we need to understand the requirement clearly. The content of each div, is that static or dynamically generated? I mean how different is the content for day-1 and day-2 for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234228/discussion-between-samir-and-learningtoanimate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content is static and maintained manually, we can implement the solution in 3 steps:

1. Create a content Array
2. Generate Random Number and store it
3. Use the random number to show specific content.

   ```
   /* 1. Create a static content array */
   $day_array = array(

    '<div id="day-1">
        <p>Show if Day 1 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-2">
        <p>Show if Day 2 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-3">
        <p>Show if Day 3 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-4">
        <p>Show if Day 4 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-5">
        <p>Show if Day 5 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-6">
        <p>Show if Day 6 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-7">
        <p>Show if Day 7 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-8">
        <p>Show if Day 8 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-9">
        <p>Show if Day 9 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>',

    '<div id="day-10">
        <p>Show if Day 10 is randomly chosen</p>
        </div>'
   );

   /* Generate Random number */
   $min = 1;
   $max = count($day_array);
   $random = mt_rand($min,$max);

   echo "Random Number is=".$random;

   /* And Save random number to a file */    
   $file = fopen("./randomnumber.txt","a+");
   fwrite($file,$random."\n");
   fclose($file);

   /* 3. Show randomly selected content */
   // $random-1 because the array index starts from 0
   // and we generated random starting from 1
   echo $day_array[$random-1];
   ```

[Working Demo](https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/92654b1)

Comment: Thank you so much for being one of the more patient people on SO, I really appreciate your help.